# Docker client API version issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run 'docker version', which gives:

```
> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
```

As it tells, client API version is 1.40.

But when I am trying to run a docker-compose command, I get error as:

```
> docker-compose up
ERROR: client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version
```

Why this message, when client API version is 1.40?

Edit: I updated docker-compose.

```
>docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.2.0
CPython version: 3.7.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

But I still see same issue:

```
>docker-compose up
ERROR: client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version
```

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, "version" in docker-copose.yml is the reason for error. It was 2 for me, and I changed it to 2.1. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`docker` and `docker-compose` are installed as separate binaries. Please check and upgrade `docker-compose` on your system

Eg, on my system:

```
 ~  docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
 ~  docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

Comment: For me, it was installed as part of docker desktop itself. And docker desktop is latest one for me...19.03.8.